# Getting column type dynamically after statement execution for SQLGetData (ODBC) in C

Tags: sql-server, odbc

A customer have a SQL table on a SQLServer (or Postgre, MySQL, anything. It's ODBC).

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (name VARCHAR(256), count INT);
INSERT INTO tbl ("duck", 42);
```

And because various reasons another customer have the same table. With a different data type, the name field is a int.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (name INT, count INT);
INSERT INTO tbl ("chicken", 45613215);
```

And I have executed a SQL statement to retrieve data (in C):

```
SQLExecDirect( hstmt, "SELECR name, count FROM tbl;", SQL_NTS );
```

According to [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlgetdata-function?view=sql-server-ver15), I'm suppose to bind a variable via `SQLGetData` to transfer the content of a column to a local variable. However, the function asks for a parameter `TargetType` to for the variable type.

```
SQLRETURN SQLGetData(  
      SQLHSTMT       StatementHandle,  
      SQLUSMALLINT   Col_or_Param_Num,  
      SQLSMALLINT    TargetType,       // This one
      SQLPOINTER     TargetValuePtr,  
      SQLLEN         BufferLength,  
      SQLLEN *       StrLen_or_IndPtr);
```

In this case I don't know the type of the column beforehand. Customers have a different type for the `name` field. And I wish to handle things differently according to the type, not relying on ODBC's automatic type conversion. The documentation didn't provide a way to dynamically acquire the column type. Nor it provided a C++ variant/any like universal container. How could I acquire the column type after statement execution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use setting table for each customer which identify the type of columns and get the return values according to the setting table